# What is "IsA()" function in C?

Tags: c, postgresql

In pure C code in different projects that i**nvolve Postgresql server programming** which I'm working with now, I keep encountering the function "IsA()" which returns a boolean and checks whether or not 2 instances of a struct belong to the same struct. I suppose.

One of them:

https://github.com/guotao0628/pipelinedb/blob/master/src/backend/executor/nodeBitmapAnd.c#L123

```
    for (i = 0; i < nplans; i++)
    {
        PlanState  *subnode = bitmapplans[i];
        TIDBitmap  *subresult;

        subresult = (TIDBitmap *) MultiExecProcNode(subnode);

        if (!subresult || !IsA(subresult, TIDBitmap))               /*what's IsA(...) ? */
            elog(ERROR, "unrecognized result from subplan");

        if (result == NULL)
            result = subresult; /* first subplan */
```

I need to port some of that C code to other strictly typed language. Hence, I need to know how "isA()" is implemented under the hood. But I haven't found it anywhere. Supposedly it's defined in some library.

Where can I find its definition?

Comment: Can it be [this](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/1aac32df89eb19949050f6f27c268122833ad036/src/include/nodes/nodes.h#L580)?

Comment: Note that `IsA()` must be a macro because it takes a type name as the second argument and no function in (standard) C can do that.  That probably means it is defined in a header file — `#define IsA(pointer, typename) …black magic…`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IsA` is a macro which is defined in [this](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/1aac32df89eb19949050f6f27c268122833ad036/src/include/nodes/nodes.h) header file in `Postgresql` source code.

Comment: Right. This is PostgreSQL specific and not related to C in general.

Comment: how did you manage to find the definition in the source code? do you have it downloaded locally?

Comment: No. There is no need to download the source code locally. You can search the source code for anything in Postgresql's official [Github](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/) repository and you should know how to search in a GitHub repo. Since macro definitions are usually found in header files, you can use advanced search to limit the search to ".h" extension files only.